# Magento - List All Subcategories Only with Include in Navigation Menu Yes

Tags: list, magento

In my magento store i have the following code to list out all subcategories as links. I only want to show categories that have `Include in Navigation Menu - Yes` in the category admin setting though.

```
<?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
<?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
            <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I know `getIncludeInMenu()` can be used to get this setting but when i try and add it into the above it shows no categories?

```
<?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
<?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>

    <!-- this makes no categories show -->
    <?php if (!$_subcategory->getIncludeInMenu()){} else { ?>

        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
            <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
            </a>
        </li>

    <?php } ?>  

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**UPDATE**

With the code above it looks like the recommended `getIncludeMenu()` function is not working on `$_subcategory` but it is working if i use it on `$_category`

Am i missing something on this line to pull in the subcategories/ child categories perhaps?

```
$_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories()
```

Comment: Is this Magento 1 or 2? Roughly which version? Can you tag it as such?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<?php if ($_subcategory->getIncludeInMenu()) { ?>

        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
            <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
            </a>
        </li>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerard but when i do that no subcategories get displayed. It looks like the `getIncludeMenu()` function is not working on `$_subcategory` but it is working if i use it on `$_category` any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

So I cam across this solution, after your foreach loop for the sub categories reload your sub categories in a variable, hope this makes sense :

```
<?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
   <?php $subcat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()); ?>
   <?php if($subcat->getIncludeInMenu()): ?>
      <li>
         <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?></a>
      </li>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
    $categories = $categoryCollection->create();
    $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $categories->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('eq'=>2));
    $categories->load();
?>
  <?php
    foreach($categories as $category):
        $catId = $category->getId();
        $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);
        $subcats = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories();
        $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
        foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
            $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
            $_outputhelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
            $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
            $sitebaseurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
            $subcaturl = $subcat->getUrl();
            if (!$_category->getData('include_in_menu')) {

                continue;

            }
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $subcat->getUrl(); ?>" id="sub_<?php echo $subcat->getId();?>" class="<?php if($subcat->getChildrenCategories()->count()):?>child_sub<?php else:?> no-child<?php endif;?>">    
            <?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>
            </a>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```